# Can RJ11 Cat3 cable be used over fibre optic cable

Tags: phone, fiber

I have a garage where the internet connection comes in from the ISP. The modem/router provided by the ISP has RJ45 connections for internet and an an RJ11 for a phone. At present, the garage is connected to the main house via a 50m conduit with a fiberoptic cable.

Can I run another fiber cable to carry the phone connection from the modem into the house? I would prefer to avoid cabling with metal as there have been lightning strikes in the area. I would worry the nearby trees would be hit and carry high voltage to either building.

Basic network structure:

```
ISP Modem Router
      |
  (Ethernet)
      |
 Media Converter
      |
  (Fiber in
  underground
   conduit)
      |
Network Switch
```

Some quick checking suggests I can use the blue and blue&white wires in a cat5/6 cable and terminate them in an RJ11. [Can I use Cat5/Cat6 instead of phone cables](https://superuser.com/questions/1049795/can-i-use-cat5-cat6-instead-of-phone-cables)
My guess is that I can pop an RJ11 on one end and an RJ45 on the other before connecting to a media converter that supports 10baseT. One of those connects to the router's phone port, the other connects to the phone on the inside of the house. Sound plausible? I have plenty of ethernet tools to terminate the cables myself.

Comment: I can easily find converters RJ11<>Fiber in both directions on Amazon and Ali Express, but I can't recommend any. Not many cheap ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a network signal converted from Rj45 to fiber and back is easy as such media-converters are a standard product made by dozens of manufacturers. You can easily get a pair of them under $100. (Don't bother with slow speed. Price difference is minimal. You might as well go for gigabit and be ready for future speed upgrades.)
Do keep in mind that the fibre-cable itself must be compatible with the fiber-optics in the converter. There are several different variants that don't always mix.

But the phone line doesn't carry a digital netwrok signal. It is purely analog and because of that it requires specialty media-converters.
POTS over fiber converters typically have a normal fiber-rj45 converter inside and connected to the RJ45 side is a micro-controller that converts the POTS signal to/from a digital data-stream that can be send over the point2point network formed by the 2 converters and the fiber-cable.

There is only a small market for those so not many people make them. They are hard to find and very expensive.

If you are worried about lightning a surge protector on each side of the phone line is probably a much cheaper alternative for the phone-line part.

Comment: Excellent advice! I hadn’t thought of a surge protector for the phone! I can see they’re very cheap. Thanks.

Comment: @The_Stewart I have some experience in this. I dealt with similar issues helping a friend run network and phone-lines between his farmhouse and several barn(s). Network for CCTV camera's (people looking to steal expensive tools and farm-equipment is a problem around here) and phone-lines so you don't have to yell back and forth all the time. Cell-phone coverage is extremely poor in the country so an old-fashioned PBX and analog phones is a cheap solution.